# Javascript (jQuery) disable page scroll when dragging items

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a widget-like system with widgets that are able to be dragged around (with jQuery draggable/sortable). The problem is now that when a user drags one of those widgets and moves the cursor on the edge, the parent div scrolls to the direction of the cursor.

A simplified layout is as follows:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width:WINDOW_WIDTH;">
  <div id="page_wrapper" style="width:10000px;">
    <div class="widget_page" style="width:WINDOW_WIDTH;">
      <div class="widget draggable"></div>
      <div class="widget draggable"></div>
      <div class="widget draggable"></div>
    </div>        
    <div class="widget_page" style="width:WINDOW_WIDTH;">
      <div class="widget draggable"></div>
      <div class="widget draggable"></div>
      <div class="widget draggable"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

is there any way i can disable the page_wrapper from scrolling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add `overflow:hidden;` in the css of the page_wrapper.

Comment: This doesn't work; the '<div>' still scrolls when the user drags a widget to the edge of the screen

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle? this is how this css is supposed to work http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_overflow&preval=hidden

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rzNDX/  if you drag one of the red rectangles to the side, you will see that a scrollbar appears and that it starts to scroll

Comment: you need to add a containment for your draggable items like this http://jsfiddle.net/SJcxX/5/

Comment: containment does not fix this, I already tried that. If you drag the cursor to the edge of the screen, the div will scroll. I believe this is standard browser behaviour

Comment: I don't think so. I've simplified even more my example for you http://jsfiddle.net/SJcxX/13/. Please note the Jquery code for the draggable elements (the containment and more important the scroll): `$( "#draggable3" ).draggable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: false });`

Comment: scroll: false did it. I can't believe i was so stupid to miss this variable. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! You are not stupid ... it happens to all of us :)

Answer (score 0):

just add css property "position as a static" on parent div for which you set the scrollbar.

```
$("selector").css("position","static");
```

ex.

```
$('.bottomSentences').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: 'clone',
        start: function(e, ui)
        {
            $(ui.helper).addClass("ui-draggable-helper");
            $("#splitSentencesDiv").css("position","static");

        }       
});
```

here in ex. splitSentencesDiv is my Div for which i set the scroll. by default its position value is relative set by bootstrap col- class.